# Why is this question about Paper Selections 'too broad'?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I was really puzzled that [What paper should a design print shop have on hand?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92979/what-paper-should-a-design-print-shop-have-on-hand) was closed as 'too broad'. In my eyes, this is a pretty decent question that can be answered in just a couple paragraphs.

I'd love to hear y'all's thoughts about this question, and exactly why it is too broad. I really don't understand why we can't have this Q on the site, and why it couldn't have a good and concise answer or two. I even see half an answer hidden in the comments--info that the Asker would certainly benefit from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's an interesting question, and *potentially* a great question. This is honestly the kind of question we need more of (...I really love paper). I can certainly see how it could be seen as both too broad and primarily opinion based as it is though.

As it is now it is basically asking for a list of opinions with little to no background information and no requirements for the recommendations; which is... well, kinda broad and opinion based...

So how can it be fixed?

We need more information. What print methods and machinery will be used and available for the paper to be used on? What kind of people and what kind of work will be being printed? Is budget a concern? Any other restrictions or requirements?

With all of that, I'd hope that'd limit the scope of the question to something more answerable. It'd certainly be less broad... and as for opinions; [they aren't always bad](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

(Unfortunately OP is the only person who can really expand on all of that, so there's not much any of us can do unless they can give us more to go on.)

---

This is, btw, just my opinion, I'd still like to know how others feel.

Comment: I didn't see the question until now, but looking at it I agree with you. Potentially interesting question but too vague at the moment.

Comment: *"As it is now it is basically asking for a list of opinions with little to no background information and no requirements for the recommendations;" Yup.. it's an open-ended shopping list... with zero indication of *anything* specific. Like asking "what could I have for dinner tonight???" The answers are nearly infinite.